# How can i check if all my checkers are in the same place?

Tags: c#, game-engine, windows-forms-designer

I need to make a backgammon game. The game is 90% done. I have to make the endgame (when you take out your checkers from the "home" i don't know how it's called in english). I have all the whitecheckers in ArrayPieseAlbe and i'm using a foreach to check if the location match.

```
public bool SuntToatePieseAlbeCasa()
        {
            foreach (PiesaAlba p in ArrayPieseAlbe)
            {
                return p.Location.X > 503; //503 is the right location 
            }
            return false;
```

PiesaAlba is the class where the white checkers are. ArrayPieseAlbe contains all the white checkers. For some strange reason this doesn't work as it's supposed to work. It's working when 7 or more checkers are in the "home" but it need for all 15 to be there to work properly. Any advices? Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Use an if statement in the loop, and only return (`false`) from the loop if the the condition _isn't met_. If you exit the loop without having returned, then the condition was met for every item, and you can therefore return `true`.

Comment: like this? { foreach (PiesaAlba p in ArrayPieseAlbe)
            {
                if (p.Location.X > 503 == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;}

Comment: See devNull's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return to true if *all* of the pieces are "home". Currently, you're returning true if *any* (i.e. at least one) of the pieces are home.

To fix this, you're logic should be:

1. Iterate through each piece and check that it is home
2. If not, immediately return false
3. If all pieces have been checked, return true

This would look something like:

```
public bool SuntToatePieseAlbeCasa()
{
    foreach (PiesaAlba p in ArrayPieseAlbe)
    {
        if (p.Location.X <= 503) //503 is the right location 
        {
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}
```

You could alternatively use the [`All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-5.0) method in System.Linq:

```
public bool SuntToatePieseAlbeCasa()
{
    return ArrayPieseAlbe.All(p => p.Location.X > 503);
}
```

Looking at the [source of `All()`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1305), it does essentially the same thing as above but uses a predicate to do the check inside of the loop:

```
public static bool All<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (!predicate(element)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: THANKS YOU SO MUCHHH